# Strange error after update to 3.4.2 with Geckodriver 0.16

Tags: python, selenium, geckodriver

Firefox got updated to version 53 and a Python script I use to snipe auctions on Ebay stopped working. At first it was complaining here:

`driver.get('https://signin.ebay.com.au/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?SignIn&ru=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ebay.com.au%2F')`

`time.sleep(10)`

`elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("fld")`

`elements[2].send_keys("your-username")`

I found out that there is a known issue with send_keys in geckodriver 0.15

I updated Selenium to 3.4.2 and gecko to 0.16. The above code works again. Yay! However, it dies (Boo!) on:

`itemidurl = "http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/" + sys.argv[1] + "?&autorefresh=true"`

`print itemidurl`

`driver.get(itemidurl)`

On that last line to be exact, so the `.get`. Btw, you can substitute any valid (active) Ebay item number in the URL. The error it gives me is:

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Reached error page: about:neterror?e=dnsNotFound&u=http%3A//pics/&c=UTF-8&f=regular&d=Firefox%20can%E2%80%99t%20find%20the%20server%20at%20pics.

I have no idea what that means! The strange thing is that it goes to the page in question just fine, but the script dies at that point. What gives?

---

**EDIT:** Let me just add the entire error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/snipr/snipr.py", line 37, in <module>
driver.get(itemidurl)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", 
line 264, in get self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", 
line 252, in execute self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-
packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 194, in 
check_response raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Reached error page: 
about:neterror?e=dnsNotFound&u=http%3A//pics/&c=UTF-
8&f=regular&d=Firefox%20can%E2%80%99t%20find%20the%20server%20at%20pics.
```

It appears that the error is coming from selenium itself and not my code. HELP!

---

**EDIT 2:** I have reproduced the error with several Ebay URLs of the same format. You can try this to reproduce the behavior: http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/162528324648?&autorefresh=true

I can get past the error by using a URL on a totally different site, which of course makes it fail on the very next step. I can wrap the `.get` in a `try/except` block and ignore the error, but that doesn't explain where the error is coming from!

Comment: Might be a geckodriver issue https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/4003 but also, you really need to provide the URL. Use a throwaway ebay item. If someone else can reproduce, there will be a cause for re-raising that Selenium issue.

Comment: @MikhailRamendik I have updated the original question to include a URL you can test this with. I have been able to reproduce the error on every URL of a similar format I have tried so far.

Comment: Added steps to reproduce the error to github here: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/4003

Comment: I got a similar problem and for me was a Firefox issue, every time that firefox make a big update all my selenium driver don't work more. to solve I had to re-install the selenium driver for firefox and gekodrive

Comment: I have already updated selenium and the geckodriver. Didn't help...